# How to get SignalR hub object to create a Duplex channel for wcfservice?

Tags: asp.net, ajax, wcf, signalr, signalr-hub

Hi we are developing a web application. In which we are storing values on session for state maintenance. It has users right and window's service connection object etc. Now we are need to update the client from server side. I used DuplexChannelFactory for two way communication with 
windows service and web server also I used SignalR for two way communication from web server and browser. I used same hub object to create DuplexChannelFactory. It works fine for me. But now my problem is I need to store that channel into session for state maintenance for both window and web server. But i am not able to get the hub object in the web server. So please help me to get the hub object to create the Duplex channel and how can I store this object into session? want your valuable suggestions...

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to create an actual Hub object. SignalR allows you to access a Hub clients outside of the Hub itself via an IHubContext.

You can get an IHubContext using `GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<T>()`.

Take a look at the "How to call client methods and manage groups from outside the Hub class" section of [this API guide](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/hubs-api/hubs-api-guide-server#callfromoutsidehub) to learn more.